# Update query to insert missing dates within a specified range in MS Access table

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Access database that is tracking a rolling 35 week window on job data. I have it automated so once a month I run a script that generates an e-mail and attaches an Excel worksheet for the appropriate program manager so they can update their crew number count projections for the next 35 weeks. The program saves a copy of the Excel sheet so I can run a compare once the sheet has been returned.

What I would like to do is add in the missing dates from their dataset prior to building the Excel sheet that gets e-mailed. That way the table where I store the dates would have an auto-generated line item number that I could reference later when I re-import the data from the Excel file.

I suppose I could just run an update query that expands all of the job records in the database to the same end date and later purge out anything that has a zero crew count as the rolling window drops away, but is there was a better way of approaching this?

Comment: Please clarify 'missing dates'. I'm guessing the last date in your DB table for the 'rolling 35' is the current week, and you want a projection to go out to 'Current + 35', or is the last date you have 1 month short of 35 weeks (since you do this monthly). I f just adding 4 weeks, then simple = run 4 insert queries to add 4 weeks; if adding 35, you could use VBA to loop thru 35 times.

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn, You are correct, current+35. Currently all jobs have end dates relative to their respective starting dates, so as a result they don't all have the same ending date. It probably is just as simple as running 4 update queries and then purging out last months items that have no data in them. Would have to come up with a routine that would add 35 weeks to new job when they are added also. Wanted to make sure that our database didn't get bloated with line items that we didn't need.

Comment: If you show us your table structure with sample data, we can help. Use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: Ron, I provided some code (see answer) that will work for adding 35 weeks for a new Job. If you can explain the rules for when/how to add one or more weeks (or is it months) for a given job, then the code can be modified. i.e (1) I assume no adds for a 'closed' job; (2) If a Job, as of today, has 10 future weeks, do you want to add 25 more weeks; (3) any other rules would be helpful.

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn, Thanks for the code sample. Here are the replies to your questions. (1) No records are added to closed jobs, they are also omitted from the select query that builds the Excel sheet to e-mail. (2) Yes, that is what I was thinking was originally going to have to happen, but the more I ponder it, I think all active jobs will wind up having the same ending date if we push the end date to 35 weeks out from when the report runs. (3)Table I am working with has 3 fields, Job_ID, Workweek(Monday date only), and Crew_num. Excel sheet goes out with previous months projections. cont.......

Comment: They edit the sheet to correct current labor projections (number in the Crew_num field) and e-mail it back. I need to correct myself, there are actually 4 fields, there is also an autogenerated LI_ID key field, that I am using for my reference point when re-importing the data. The reason I want to provide all of the possible date ranges, is that the workweek is restricted to Monday only, do not want to chance someone keying in a date that does not fall on a Monday and botching up the update process. Thank you for all your feedback.

Comment: Would help to understand the duration of your 'Jobs'. Let's say I put together a project plan to build a house and I know the expected ending date is 16 weeks from the start date. Thus I would want my Excel sheet to go for 16 weeks plus a 'delay' factor. (1) Do you have a planned 'End' date? If so, I doubt you want 35 weeks past the end date -- maybe 4, 8 or 12? (2) Does your DB have a planned end date field? If so, we can use that to assist. (3) I assume elsewhere in your DB your 'StartDate' is already a Monday? Am changing code to your fld names, but will wait for your feedback.

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn, The DB is basically 3 tables. Jobdata table that stores general information about the job, PMName, Job Name, Job_Id, Foreman, Active, Closed, Priority. SiteData table that stores information for each work week, LI_ID(autogen key) ,  Job_Id, workweek, CrewNum. PM table that store information about the Program managers, PMName, e-mail, phone. (1) There is no planned end date. PM's just enter a crew count for the weeks they anticipate workers are needed. (2) No field for this. (3) No start date field.

Comment: Since you don't have a 'planned end date' to rely on, you will need to state how many weeks out into the future you want to have. i.e. If you ALWAYS want +35 beyond the date you run, please say so. If you want some other number, then what is that number and what rule is used to determine that number to add?

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn , yes always  +35 from the date run. Sorry if that wasn't very clear from the beginning. Unfortunately when they set up jobs initially they only enter crew data numbers for the anticipated weeks needed. So if a PM needs a crew of 60 people from 5-2-16 thru 5-16-16. that will be the only records in the database for that job. There are no placeholders in the record set for the data within the range of 10-26-15 thru 6-27-16, other than the initial range that was entered when they set the job up.

Comment: Based on latest info, try the code in the Answer. Will add 35 dates after run date; will add missing dates -- if within 4 weeks of run date. Requires your table to have unique key on Job_ID + WeekDate. Golfing on Tuesday!

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn , Thank you so much for this solution. After a little fine tuning to align things with my dataset, this functions flawlessly. I hope you had a great day golfing, I definitely owe you a round or two at the 19th tee. Thanks again, Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will:
1. Add missing dates (but only if within 4 weeks of run date)
2. Add 35 new 'week' records to past the current date

This code requires your table design to have a Unique Key of Job_ID + WeekDate

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim dbs     As DAO.Database
Dim rsJobs  As DAO.recordSet
Dim rsWeek  As DAO.recordSet

Function Create_New_Weeks()
Dim strSQL  As String
Dim i       As Integer
Dim dStartDate      As Date
Dim dEndDate        As Date
Dim dPriorMonday    As Date
Dim dTempDate       As Date
Dim strJobID        As String

Const iWksToAdd = 35            ' Change as desired

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    ' Get Job_ID and Week records for all OPEN Jobs.
    ' Expect this to possibly be the first date, possibly a gap in dates, then
    ' one or more weekly dates.
    strSQL = "SELECT tblProjects.Job_ID, tblProjects.DateEnded, tblJobWeeks.WorkWeek " & _
                "FROM tblProjects INNER JOIN tblJobWeeks ON tblProjects.Job_ID = tblJobWeeks.Job_ID " & _
                "WHERE (((tblProjects.DateEnded) Is Null)) " & _
                "ORDER BY tblProjects.Job_ID, tblJobWeeks.WorkWeek;"
    Set rsJobs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If rsJobs.EOF Then
        MsgBox "No Jobs found!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "No Jobs"
        GoTo Exit_Code
    Else
        rsJobs.MoveFirst
    End If

    ' First, find prior Monday's date as a baseline
    dPriorMonday = DateAdd("ww", -1, Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 1))

    ' Calculate +35 weeks -- and make sure the date will be a monday.
    If Weekday(Date, 1) = 2 Then
        dEndDate = DateAdd("ww", iWksToAdd, Date)
    Else
        dEndDate = DateAdd("ww", iWksToAdd, dPriorMonday)
    End If

    ' Open the 'Weekly' table for inserting 35 new records, plus missing dates
    strSQL = "select * from tblJobWeeks order by Job_ID, WorkWeek"
    Set rsWeek = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    ' FYI: It doesn't make sense to add records between the 'start' date and + 35 weeks, then
    ' have your monthly process delete empty ones from prior months.
    ' This code will only add missing records going back 4 weeks.

    ' Your notes indicated there would be at least two records for any given Job. If that is
    ' not correct, this code may not work!

    ' Save the starting point
    strJobID = rsJobs!Job_ID
    dTempDate = rsJobs!WorkWeek
    Do While Not rsJobs.EOF
        Debug.Print "Job: " & rsJobs!Job_ID & vbTab & "First Date: " & rsJobs!WorkWeek & vbTab & "W/E: " & rsJobs!WorkWeek
        If strJobID <> rsJobs!Job_ID Then   ' We have changed to a NEW Job_ID
            ' Fill the +35 weeks
            ' Only add prior 4 wks , then +35
            If dTempDate < dEndDate Then dTempDate = DateAdd("ww", -3, dPriorMonday)    ' Get date from 3 or 4 weeks back.
            Do
                If dTempDate < dEndDate Then
                    ' Don't add dates over 4 weeks old - Remove this if necessary
                    If dTempDate >= DateAdd("ww", -4, Date) Then
                        Debug.Print "Insert ID: " & strJobID & vbTab & dTempDate
                        Add_Week strJobID, dTempDate
                    Else
                        Debug.Print "Skip - Older than 4 weeks: " & vbTab & dTempDate
                    End If
                    dTempDate = DateAdd("ww", 1, dTempDate)
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
            strJobID = rsJobs!Job_ID
            dTempDate = DateAdd("ww", 1, rsJobs!WorkWeek)       ' Should be the FIRST date for this Job
        Else
            If rsJobs!WorkWeek = dTempDate Then
                dTempDate = DateAdd("ww", 1, dTempDate)
            Else
                ' Don't add dates over 4 weeks old - Remove this if necessary
                If dTempDate > DateAdd("ww", -4, Date) Then
                    Debug.Print "Insert ID: " & strJobID & vbTab & dTempDate
                    Add_Week strJobID, dTempDate
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Skip - Older than 4 weeks: " & vbTab & dTempDate
                End If
                dTempDate = DateAdd("ww", 1, dTempDate)
            End If
        End If
        rsJobs.MoveNext
    Loop

    'Check if last ID has +35 dates
    If dTempDate < dEndDate Then
        Do Until dEndDate = dTempDate
            ' Don't add dates over 4 weeks old - Remove this if necessary
            If dTempDate > DateAdd("ww", -4, Date) Then
                Debug.Print "Insert ID: " & strJobID & vbTab & dTempDate
                Add_Week strJobID, dTempDate
            Else
                Debug.Print "Skip - Older than 4 weeks: " & vbTab & dTempDate
            End If
            dTempDate = DateAdd("ww", 1, dTempDate)
        Loop
    End If

Exit_Code:
    If Not rsJobs Is Nothing Then
        rsJobs.Close
        Set rsJobs = Nothing
    End If
    If Not rsWeek Is Nothing Then
        rsWeek.Close
        Set rsWeek = Nothing
    End If
    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Exit Function
Error_Trap:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In:       Create_New_Weeks"
    ' If duplicate record, ignore
    If Err.Number = 3022 Then
        Resume Next
    End If
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In: Create_New_Weeks"
    Create_New_Weeks = "Error: " & Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In: Create_New_Weeks"
    Resume Exit_Code
    Resume
End Function

Function Add_Week(strID As String, dDate As Date)
    With rsWeek
        .AddNew
        !Job_ID = strID
        !WorkWeek = dDate
        !Crew_Num = 0
        .Update
    End With

End Function
```